# Getting element with class name in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this span

```
 <span *ngFor="let list of lists[0].question; let i = index" id="word{{ i }}" (click)="changestyle($event)" class="highlight">
  {{ list}}
</span>
```

when i try to get all the element with class highlight

```
check() {
    let highlight_text= $('.highlight');
    console.log(highlight_text.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < highlight_text.length; i++) {
```

Getting length 0 but i have class with this name it should return those elements.

Any solution. Thanks

Comment: the solution is to let go of jQuery when you work with Angular, it is a sizeable job to make them work well together

Comment: @TheFabio How will i access the span with certain id and classes and change the style dynamically in angular ?

Comment: @user3653474 you can use `document.getElementByClassName('highlight')`

Comment: @GRD Can i use `this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.highlight');`?

Comment: you should avoid querying the dom in Angular... as most content is generated dynamically, the idea is to have some data in your component influencing how the html is generated. So changing the component data causes the html to change.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? I believe it's not just selecting some spans but you are trying to do something with them later. And that something pretty much determinates the best solution for you

Comment: Is lists[0].question  producing a list?

Comment: @user3653474 yes, you can use that too

Answer (score 0):

The problem concerns the call of the `check` method, it **shouldn't** be in the `ngOnInit` I tried it using  `ngAfterViewInit` as following:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.check();
  }
```

and I found the length is >0

Answer (score 0):

Answering to **@The Fabio**'s comment below his answer and providing a possible answer to the original question.

Why it's not good to use the function to evaluate a class within `[ngClass]`? Or, more generally speaking, why it's a bad idea to use function calls in Angular template expressions?

The problem is caused by the fact that the Angular change detection needs to call the function to see if there was some change => while looping through large lists you'll end up calling the function hundreds of times even when the real change does not affect it. Such function will be executed every time you click on some button, write into a binded input and so on. See the [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y8uacq?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

When trying to solve the original problem, it's good to have a look on the original list and see what can be done with it. I strongly suggest to use the **View Model** which provides extended properties to the original **Data Model**.

```typescript
// Possible Question View Model
// extending the original one allows to add new properties while keeping the old ones
interface IQuestionVM extends IQuestionDTO { 
  hasHighlight: boolean
}

//then somewhere in the code, ngOnInit is safe place for this
this.processedQuestions: Array<IQuestionVM> = this.lists[0]question.map(q => ({
 ...q, // spread the original object
 hasHighlight: q.something === 0 // evaluate the condition and assign to extended property
}))
```

This will allow to simplify and optimize the HTML template:

```html
<span 
  *ngFor="let list of processedQuestions; let i = index" id="word{{ i }}"
  (click)="changestyle($event)"
  [ngClass]="{ 'highlight': list.hasHighlight }"  
>
  {{ list }}
</span>
```

This approach eliminates the need for a special function to check the class, eliminates the need to look for the elements, and at the same time makes it easier to handle highlight updates. No additional variables, arrays, functions, jQuery are longer necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Mixing angular and jQuery you would be up to a lot of monkey-patching...

If the objective is to set the class on the element based on attributes, the best bet is the [ngClass Directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass):

```
<span *ngFor="let list of lists[0].question; let i = index" id="word{{ i }}" (click)="changestyle($event)" [ngClass] = {'highlight': shouldHighlight(list)}>
  {{ list}}
</span>
```

and in the component you create a function

```
shouldHighlight(list) {
  // your condition, returning true or false
}
```

Comment: This is far from ideal. The `shouldHighlight` function is executed every time the change detection runs. Which for the list like one above means multiple unnecessary calls.

Comment: @mat.hudak I think you have missed the comments in the question, which this answer is targeted for... but in trying to understand your point, it can be better to have data manipulation instead of using a function in some cases. Would you care to explain the OP why it is the case, instead of proposing this baseless comment?